# Flask Blueprints and werkzeug.contrib.cache

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I am using werkzeug caching to cache a commonly used object in memory between requests.  I have been doing a lot of refactoring and started using blue prints, but now the application hard crashes when it tries to write to the cache. I can't get any debug information on it because it just dies. Anyone have any idea where to look, or a better way to approach this? The data I am reading from a database rarely ever changes so I want to cache it in the webserver across requests and have it timeout and refresh every 10 or 20 minutes.

Comment: There should be output - how are you running the application? Is [debug mode](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/config/#builtin-configuration-values) enabled? If you're running your application in a terminal, you should at least get a traceback if it crashes.

Comment: Also, some code from your project would be helpful.

Comment: Please share some code to give us an idea.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize for such little information, I had little to go on and I figured I would throw it out there.  So it turns out this was a big red herring.

The real answer is...I am an idiot.

I was caching an object that had overridden the **getattr** function, which had a really bad typo.

```
return self.__getatribute__(name)
```

Notice, the missing t in getattribute.  This caused an infinite loop and made the application die silently.  Thanks for the help, next time i'll give some more info.